# Why is there no option to install ubuntu alongside windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

I want to dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu but I can't see the option to install alongside windows 10 during ubuntu installation. Yet ubuntu installer recognizes windows 10. My pc has 4 partitions. Please help

Answer (score 10):

You need unallocated space for that option to show.

If you do not have that you will need to shrink one of your partitions (to the size of the Ubuntu installation you want to use; at least a minimum of 30Gb).

Comment: Thanks i deleted my drive D and had unallocated space and the option was available.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 that is preinstalled on a laptop is normally installed in UEFI mode. In the *Boot* tab of the BIOS settings uncheck the Legacy option making the USB flash drive bootable in UEFI mode.

Comment: Thank you. This saved my life. Alongside option appeared when I chose UEFI boot option, but not when I chose Legacy boot option.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have a Windows installation that does not use up all the Primary partitions, none of which is an extended partition. I hit this recently trying to do an install. To put it another way, you must have:
Either:

1. three or fewer Primary partitions, or
2. One of your Primary partitions must be a container for extended partitions.

Or you have to re-arrange things to meet these requirements.

Martin

Comment: Recent OSs use GPT which does not have any concept of Primary/Extended partitions.